# spring xslt view

Tags: spring, xslt, spring-mvc

I want to add xslt view to my spring web application. But my web application configured using spring annotations and hence it does not have any expicitly declared view resolvers. I tried to add a view resolver specially for xslt but the rest of my application becomes unresolvable. It it possible to configure xslt view only using annotations? Or may be there is another solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that it would suffice to write a ViewResolver class and annotate it as `@Component`, provided that you have `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in your xml context.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I found better solution. To keep annotation configuration of views I declared explicitly InternalResourceViewResolver and resolver for my xslt view. Configuration of InternalResourceViewResolver is here [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-viewresolver-chaining). All views are correctly resolved. As a rule, I should think twice before asking :)